# Riemann integral and Simple function

Tags: calculus, riemann-integration

I am so confusing that represent the Riemann Sum in terms of the Simple function. Consider initial tagged partition approach to Riemann Sum is $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^n f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i)$$ This representation makes sense to me, however, I also have seen the representation(simple function) like below$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^nf(t_i)\chi_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]}$$.

Now consider a constant function, $f:\mathbb{R}\to \{c\}$, Riemann sum approach I could see it's calculating the area under the line $c$, but that characteristic functions taking values $\{0,1\}$ makes me hard to see what is going on.

Please enlighten me. Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's the same approche. Notice that if $$g(x)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)\chi_{[x_i,x_{i+1}]},$$
then you define $$\int g:=\sum_{i=1}^n f(t_i)(x_{i+1}-x_i).$$

Comment: would you please explain why does integrate of characteristic function would be $(x_{i+1}-x_i)$

Comment: $$\int \chi_{[a,b]}(x)dx=\int_a^bdx=b-a.$$

Comment: Is this a definition? I was trying search online, and have seen silimiar things define on more general space, would you please refer me something to look in depth. Cheers

Comment: You can see it as definition, but as you mention (in Riemann context), $\int f$ is the area between $x$ axis and $f$. So, $\chi_{[a,b]}$ is $1$ on $[a,b]$ and $0$ anywhere else. So, $\int\chi_{[a,b]}$ is the area of the rectangle $[a,b]\times [0,1]$ which is indeed $(b-a)\times 1=b-a$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. It's seems to me that almost every positive function can be rewrite as a simple function, is that true?

Comment: No this is not true. For example $\chi_{\mathbb Q}$ cannot.

Comment: Could you explain why? I could see the dirichlet functions taking 1 on rational and 0 on irrational, and simply rewrite as a linear combination.

Comment: So, I guess what you mean by "all positive function can be re-write as simple function" is rather : "all positiv function is a pointwise limit of a linear combinaison of step function", no ? (or do you really mean simple function ? Because simple function is more general than step function).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108489/discussion-between-ljng-and-walace).